# Reading binary data in python

Tags: python, file, binary

Firstly, before this question gets marked as duplicate, I'm aware others have asked similar questions but there doesn't seem to be a clear explanation. I'm trying to read in a binary file into an 2D array (documented well here http://nsidc.org/data/docs/daac/nsidc0051_gsfc_seaice.gd.html).

The header is a 300 byte array.

So far, I have;

```
import struct

with open("nt_197912_n07_v1.1_n.bin",mode='rb') as file:
    filecontent = file.read()

x = struct.unpack("iiii",filecontent[:300])
```

Throws up an error of string argument length.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Reading the Data (Short Answer)

After you have determined the size of the grid (`n_rows`x`n_cols` = 448x304) from your header (see below), you can simply read the data using [`numpy.frombuffer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html).

```
import numpy as np

#...

#Get data from Numpy buffer
dt = np.dtype(('>u1', (n_rows, n_cols)))
x = np.frombuffer(filecontent[300:], dt) #we know the data starts from idx 300 onwards

#Remove unnecessary dimension that numpy gave us
x = x[0,:,:]
```

The `'>u1'` specifies the format of the data, in this case **unsigned** integers of size 1-byte, that are big-endian format.

Plotting this with `matplotlib.pyplot`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#...

plt.imshow(x, extent=[0,3,-3,3], aspect="auto")
plt.show()
```

The `extent=` option simply specifies the axis values, you can change these to lat/lon for example (parsed from your header)

[image: Output]

### Explanation of Error from .unpack()

From the [docs for `struct.unpack(fmt, string)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack):

> The string must contain exactly the amount of data required by the format (`len(string)` must equal `calcsize(fmt)`)

You can determine the size specified in the format string (`fmt`) by looking at the [Format Characters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters) section.

Your `fmt` in `struct.unpack("iiii",filecontent[:300])`, specifies 4 int types (you can also use `4i` = `iiii` for simplicity), each of which have size 4, requiring a string of length 16.

Your string (`filecontent[:300]`) is of length 300, whilst your `fmt` is asking for a string of length 16, hence the error.

### Example Usage of .unpack()

As an example, reading your supplied document I extracted the first 21*6 bytes, which has format:

> a 21-element array of 6-byte character strings that contain information such as polar stereographic grid characteristics

With:

```
x = struct.unpack("6s"*21, filecontent[:126])
```

This returns a tuple of 21 elements. Note the whitespace padding in some elements to meet the 6-byte requirement.

```
>> print x
    # ('00255\x00', '  304\x00', '  448\x00', '1.799\x00', '39.43\x00', '45.00\x00', '558.4\x00', '154.0\x00', '234.0\x00', '
    # SMMR\x00', '07 cn\x00', '  336\x00', ' 0000\x00', ' 0034\x00', '  364\x00', ' 0000\x00', ' 0046\x00', ' 1979\x00', '  33
    # 6\x00', '  000\x00', '00250\x00')
```

Notes:

- The first argument `fmt`, `"6s"*21` is a string with `6s` repeated 21
  times. Each format-character `6s` represents one string of 6-bytes
  (see below), this will match the required format specified in your
  document.
- The number `126` in `filecontent[:126]` is calculated as `6*21 = 126`.
- Note that for the `s` (string) specifier, the preceding number **does
  not** mean to repeat the format character 6 times (as it would
  normally for other format characters). Instead, it specifies the size
  of the string. `s` represents a 1-byte string, whilst `6s` represents
  a 6-byte string.

### More Extensive Solution for Header Reading (Long)

Because the binary data must be manually specified, this may be tedious to do in source code. You can consider using some configuration file (like `.ini` file)

This function will read the header and store it in a dictionary, where the structure is given from a `.ini` file

```
# user configparser for Python 3x
import ConfigParser

def read_header(data, config_file):
    """
    Read binary data specified by a INI file which specifies the structure
    """

    with open(config_file) as fd:

        #Init the config class
        conf = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        conf.readfp(fd)

        #preallocate dictionary to store data
        header = {}

        #Iterate over the key-value pairs under the
        #'Structure' section
        for key in conf.options('structure'):

            #determine the string properties
            start_idx, end_idx = [int(x) for x in conf.get('structure', key).split(',')]
            start_idx -= 1 #remember python is zero indexed!
            strLength = end_idx - start_idx

            #Get the data
            header[key] = struct.unpack("%is" % strLength, data[start_idx:end_idx])

            #Format the data
            header[key] = [x.strip() for x in header[key]]
            header[key] = [x.replace('\x00', '') for x in header[key]]

        #Unmap from list-type
        #use .items() for Python 3x
        header = {k:v[0] for k, v in header.iteritems()}

    return header
```

An example `.ini` file below. The key is the name to use when storing the data, and the values is a comma-separated pair of values, the first being the starting index and the second being the ending index. **These values were taken from Table 1 in your document.**

```
[structure]
missing_data: 1, 6
n_cols: 7, 12
n_rows: 13, 18
latitude_enclosed: 25, 30
```

This function can be used as follows:

```
header = read_header(filecontent, 'headerStructure.ini')
n_cols = int(header['n_cols'])
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the response and time, I will try this and will get back to you later/mark answer if it works. To me seems much more logical to store gridded data in NetCDF, but hey!

Comment: So transfered to the question the last line should be written as `x = struct.unpack("75i", filecontent[:300])`?

Comment: So the answer has shown me how to obtain some of the header, the question is how would I modify struct.unpack to obtain the data 304 columns x 448 rows (though it'll probably give me a stream of numbers rather than a 2d matrix).

Comment: @JamesWarner, updated the answer to read in your data. I've also included a function example to help you read in the header file with structure.

Comment: Sorry I realised I was confused about what you were asking, you indexing `[:300]` had me believe you only cared about the header. After re-reading I realised you want the data, and not the header. Tell me if you want me to remove the header parts of the answer (as it may be long and confusing).

Comment: That's for the comprehensive solution. The data values I get are different from the expected values (table 6 in the doc). Is it unpacking the data correctly?

Comment: @JamesWarner, updated the answer. The issue was with using an signed `int` ('i') as opposed to an unsigned `int` ('u'), as the values range from 0 to 255. I **could not** mask the null values with Gray correctly, and if you look at the [browse comparison image](ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/pub/DATASETS/nsidc0051_gsfc_nasateam_seaice/final-gsfc/browse/north/monthly/nt_197912_n07_v1.1_n.png), you can see the differences